# How do i import sql dump to mysql database

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1142

So I have this problem. I cant import sql dump to database and im getting this error. I've done database imports couple times but this is the first time im getting error like this. I've tried granting permission for database with GRANT TRIGGER user but that didn't work.

Any help would be appriciated.

error
[image]

Thanks

Comment: What about the user `wp_8qlgf` do they have the relevant permissions. Simple solution would be to run the Restore having logged onto `phpMyAdmin` as `root` (who can do anything)

Comment: Okay i found a solution. Had to change user privileges to ALL PRIVILEGES in root phpmyadmin. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: root Already has all privilages!